# Using Jenkins and Terraform EC2 auto deploy issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, automation, terraform

I am new to DevOps. I am trying to deploy EC2 instances using the following script. It is failing on Terraform initializing stage. I do have the terraform init in my code. where is the issue?

```
pipeline {

    parameters {
        string(name: 'environment', defaultValue: 'terraform', description: 'Workspace/environment file to use for deployment')
        booleanParam(name: 'autoApprove', defaultValue: false, description: 'Automatically run apply after generating plan?')

    }


     environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    }

   agent  any
        options {
                timestamps ()
                        }
    stages {
        stage('checkout') {
            steps {
                 script{
                        dir("terraform")
                        {
                            git "https://github.com/Ravinderhub/Jenkins-Terraform-AWS.git"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        stage('Plan') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform init -input=false'
                sh 'pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform workspace new ${environment}'
                sh 'pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform workspace select ${environment}'
                sh "pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ;terraform plan -input=false -out tfplan "
                sh 'pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ;terraform show -no-color tfplan > tfplan.txt'
            }
        }
        stage('Approval') {
           when {
               not {
                   equals expected: true, actual: params.autoApprove
               }
           }

           steps {
               script {
                    def plan = readFile 'terraform/aws-instance-first-script/tfplan.txt'
                    input message: "Do you want to apply the plan?",
                    parameters: [text(name: 'Plan', description: 'Please review the plan', defaultValue: plan)]
               }
           }
       }

        stage('Apply') {
            steps {
                sh "pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform apply -input=false tfplan"
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Getting the following error and I think the issue is on the below scripting line need to be modified here is the error>>>The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
             Here is the script line>>>   sh 'pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform init -input=false'

Answer (score 0):

There is an invalid variable in the configuration which prevents initialization.

`ami_id` variable [defines an invalid type](https://github.com/Ravinderhub/Jenkins-Terraform-AWS/blob/1cc3e2634400582648a46c20ad8206344cf15cee/aws-instance-first-script/variables.tf#L6).

Correct that to:

```
variable "ami_id" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    us-east-1    = "ami-035b3c7efe6d061d5"
    eu-west-2    = "ami-132b3c7efe6sdfdsfd"
    eu-central-1 = "ami-9787h5h6nsn"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the above in my code and i was getting the error and changed it to map1. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The type ought to be "map" not "map1".

Comment: yes i know.. i have changed it and i am still getting the same error. The reason i put 1 to see if the error goes away. with 1 or without i still get the same error. That is what i trying to say!!

Comment: Do you own the repository `https://github.com/Ravinderhub/Jenkins-Terraform-AWS.git` in the workflow configuration file and have the changes been applied there?

Comment: Yes i own the repository!! Yes changes has been made on the repo and committed as well.

Comment: here is the error>>>>> The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which moduiles and providers need to be installed

Comment: Trying running `pwd;cd terraform/aws-instance-first-script ; terraform validate` in as the first command in "Plan" step and report on the output of that.